# Import JavaScript tag inside script in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, widget, scada

I am making a HTML5 widget for a SCADA.

The widget generates a custom_widget.js, witch I have modified to this.

```
// Subscribes to receive property changes
cwidget.on("Data", function() {

var Data = document.getElementsByName("Data")
var Data.scr = cwidget.Data;

});
```

The custom_widget.js is called in my HTML.
And I would like to use the Data tag inside a Script, in the HTML.

What is the syntax for importing the tag in the HTML?

From the technical manual for the SCADA program, I have this example.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
    <head>
        <script src="../Resources/Apis/Proxy.js" cwidget="MyWidget"></script>
        <script src="./custom_widget.js"></script>
        <title>MyWidget</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="myFrame" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

custom_widget.js

```
cwidget.on("URL", function() {
    
    var myFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    myFrame.onload = cwidget.dispatchEvent("PageLoaded");
    myFrame.src = cwidget.URL;
                
});
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element. You need to index it.

Comment: And `.scr` looks like a typo for `.src`

Comment: What is `cwidget`?

Comment: I assume the cwidget is a function in the json file, that is generated with the custom_widget.js. I am new to this, and only have a technical manual, with a simple example. 

cwidget.on("URL", function() {
    
    var myFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    myFrame.onload = cwidget.dispatchEvent("PageLoaded");
    myFrame.src = cwidget.URL;
                
});